# Fix 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError' conflict between ReportPortal & com.fasterxml.jackson in Maven Cucumber project

Tags: maven, dependency-management, conflict, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I'm using the Report Portal dependency in my Maven Cucumber project, along with a separate JAR library that I've incorporated by installing it in the M2 folder. Both of these libraries internally rely on the 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat' dependency. However, I'm encountering an issue:

*Error*:
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.ContentReference com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.javaprop.JavaPropsFactory._createContentReference(java.lang.Object)'
**

ReportPortal is already developed, and it's necessary for my project. Yet, my project also requires the 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat' dependency.

How can I address this conflict/issue?
Could you help me resolve to this issue?